# Key establishment protocols other than Diffie-Hellman

Tags: key-exchange

Are there any key agreement/exchange/establishment protocols which are NOT based around the Diffie-Hellman protocol or handshakes using public key cryptograaphy? DH seems to form the basis of this single class and I'd rather use something different than this stale, old one.

**Update #1:** I've found [Algebraic Eraser](https://www.google.com/search?q="Algebraic+Eraser") seems to be the one key establishment algorithm that is not based on Diffie-Hellman, but I am finding references to an "AEDH".

Comment: 1) Just because something is old doesn't mean it is bad  or "stale".  2) While public key cryptography is no longer new there are newer PK algorithms, such as those based around ECC. 3) Are you aware of MQV? 4) Are you aware symmetric key cryptography can be used to perform key exchange?

Comment: In fact, quite the opposite: brand-new methods are automatically suspect, and only when something's been around for long enough (measured in competent analysis done instead of years since introduction) can you start to consider it to be possibly secure. If no vulnerabilities have been found in two systems, the older one is likely *better* if it's had more analysis on it. If you just want to do something new for its own sake, the place for that is not in the crypto of a non-toy project.

Comment: Check out Merkle's puzzles; they were an inspiration for DH: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%27s_Puzzles

Comment: There are a lot of schemes which are not based on DH/ discrete logarithm problems. For instance, NewHope is a lattice based key establishment scheme which is also resistant against quantum computers.